# Python import statement without a from clause imports a class not a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

As shown in the simple test case below, an import statement imports a class instead of a module with the same name, when that class is imported in the package's `__init__.py`.

Is this the expected behavior, or a bug? Whichever the case, it would be helpful if anyone could cite any relevant documentation or bug reports. If a bug, it would be useful to know what the intended behavior is: should the module pkg.a be imported, or should an error be raised?

### Package layout

```
C:\...\imp_test
|
\---pkg
        a.py
        __init__.py
```

### Files

**__init__.py**

```
from .a import a
```

**a.py**

```
class a:
    pass
```

### Result

```
C:\...\imp_test> python
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23)
[MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda custom (64-bit) on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pkg.a
>>> type(pkg.a)
<class 'type'>
>>> var = pkg.a()
>>>
```

Comment: With `from .a import a` you reassign the name `pkg.a` to `pkg.a.a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:**

This is a namespace collision between the module binding a in pkg and the variable binding a in pkg.
This is expected behaviour as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules)

**Old:**

I believe this is because of the finder used by the import statement.
The finder will search the package first before the module path, and because it finds a path that matches it immediately returns.

I took a look at the python import docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) and found this little snippet

> When the name variable is of the form package.module, normally, the top-level package (the name up till the first dot) is returned, not the module named by name. However, when a non-empty fromlist argument is given, the module named by name is returned.

If you want to force a module import you can use the import_module function

```
import importlib
a = importlib.import_module('pkg.a')
```

Comment: So it looks like this explains *why* import behaves this way, but would you agree it seems to be unintended behavior that could be considered a bug? For example, if I add a `class b` to `__init__.py`, then `import pkg.b` will raise ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: After looking at this again, I think this is a namespace collision between the package variable a and the module a. I don't think this is a bug in python. I will update my answer.

Comment: @echo This isn't a bug, you explicitly told Python to reuse this name. How will you refer to that module other than with `pkg.a`? - and that name has been reassigned by you.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Can you help me understand what I'm missing here? `__init__.py` runs first, which binds the name `pkg.a` to the class. Why shouldn't importing `pkg.a` replace that binding? For example, if I add `from . import c as a` to the end of `__init__.py`, where `c.py` defines `class c`, then the binding is replaced.